# Determine the value of the new record owner in JavaScript save event

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

We have a security requirement on Case such that after the user has selected a new owner via the OOB assign button we ask for confirmation to proceed only if the newly selected owner is a User.

I therefore need to prompt the user in JavaScript before the record is saved/assigned.  Using the event context I am able to determine if the save event was triggered by an ownership change but I can't see anyway of determining what the value is for the new owner.

I have the following JavaScript event triggered on save of the Case...

```
if (ctx.getEventArgs().getSaveMode() == 47) {
    //I need to access the new owner here to check if it's a user
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute('ownerid').getValue() // <-- This is still the current owner
    Xrm.Utility.confirmDialog(user_assignment_prompt,
        function () { }, //Yes
        function () { ctx.getEventArgs().preventDefault(); }); //No
}
```

I don't want to have to override the Assign button on Case as we'd then have to duplicate the assign dialog functionality.

Comment: A plugin in this case is better

Comment: This won't work in a plugin.  I gave this some thought by resetting the assignee in the plugin to the current owner effectively cancelling the initial assign (although it still occurs), adding the new assignee to a pending field and checking for this value when the form reloads.  I can then ask for confirmation in JS and reissue the assign request.  The problem is the form is closed on assignment so you can't immediately display the confirmation message until the form is reopened leaving the user thinking the record has been assigned when it's actually still awaiting confirmation.

Comment: and how you plan to stop the user to assign the owner from a case view? when the case is created you can enforce the selection of a user by javascript inside the onchange event of the ownerid field or inside the onsave event, when the record is assigned after, a plugin (7 rows) is enough to stop the assignment to a team.

Comment: Selecting a Team is valid in some circumstances and I understand this is easily restricted in a plugin but that's not the issue.  We want to understand how we PROMPT FOR CONFIRMATION before saving the record only when assigning to a user, hence the need to know who the new assignee is in the on save JavaScript.  We only care about updates as cases are created only from SharePoint.  The ownerid field doesn't change when you assign via the OOB assign button as I noted in my original code sample so we can't read the value of the new owner in JavaScript prior to save, which is the issue.

Comment: the OOB assign button can be controlled (means check for the new owner value) only by a plugin. Also if you can create the confirmation in your form, it will not be prompted when a user change the owner from a view or from outlook client. Create a boolean field (like "I agree to assign to user X") and inside the plugin check when the assignee is user X if the boolean field is set to true.

Comment: However this is how I will implement this requirement considering you wrote that you prefer to don't rewrite the OOB assign dialog